# Can Two Bluetooth LE (4.0) Devices talk to each other?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Can Two Bluetooth LE  (4.0) Devices talk to each other ?

A good example can be if two FitBit devices talk to each other .Just pass basic information ?
or One Coin Device communicate each to other ? (https://onlycoin.com/)

As of today we see most BLE Devices like fitbit communicate back to Iphone/Android Only .
Wont it be possible to have both FitBit deices communicate each other ?

I am thinking of creating a "Card 1: Bluetooth Card(LE 4.0)" which when Contacted with another "Card 2: Bluetooth Card(LE 4.0)" can exchange some date . After the exchange Card 1 will send the data it got from Card 2 to an IOS /Android device and the same applies to Card 2 . Is this possible at all ?

Answer (score 6):

What you want to achieve is currently not doable. Bluetooth Low Energy (v4.0) only allows the star topology configuration, i.e. Only one master and multiple slaves; the master can talk to the slaves at the same time but the slaves cannot talk to each other. According to the [Bluetooth website](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/low-energy-tech-info.aspx), they state:

"Bluetooth low energy technology uses a 32 bit access address on every packet for each slave, allowing billions of devices to be connected. The technology is optimized for one-to-one connections while allowing one-to-many connections using a star topology. With the use of quick connections and disconnections, data can move in a mesh-like topology without the complexities of maintaining a mesh network".

One way to achieve what you want is to switch roles between transmissions (i.e. the device that was once a slave then becomes a master) but this will be very complicated and many BLE chips do not support this feature.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Hi Yousif, Thanks for the details  . .. As per BLE 4.1 i am thinking if this can be doable ..Below Link has the details [link](http://9to5mac.com/2013/12/05/bluetooth-4-1-will-bring-more-reliable-automatic-connections-multiple-roles-more-via-software-update/) ..Please let me know your thoughts